# ASP.NET 5/MVC 6 Redirect During Authentication Middleware Events

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-core-mvc, middleware

What I am wanting to do is create a database record and redirect a user to a special page the first time that they sign into a site - regardless of the original request URL.  Subsequent signins should update a last logged in field in the database.

I'm using an external authentication source with Cookie Authentication.  It seems intuitive to do these things during the `OnSignedIn` event for the Cookie Authentication.  The database parts of this process work fine.  The problem redirecting to the special landing page during their first ever signin.

Here is how the Cookie Authentication is configured:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(options =>
{   
    options.AuthenticationScheme = "Cookies";
    options.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
    options.AutomaticChallenge = true;

    options.LoginPath = "/login";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/access-denied";

    options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
    {
        OnSignedIn = context =>
        {
            var userRecord = userService.GetUser(context.Principal.Identity.Name);

            if (userRecord == null)
            {
                userService.CreateUser(context.Principal.Identity.Name);

                // Does set a cookie successfully.
                context.Response.Cookies.Append("FirstTimeUser", "true");   
                // Does not redirect but continues on to the originally requested URL.
                context.Response.Redirect("/special-first-timer-page");     
            }
            else
            {
                userService.RecordLogin(userRecord);
            }

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    };
});
```

I've worked around this by adding an additional piece of middleware and leveraging the fact that I can set a cookie during the `OnSignedIn` event.

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    if (context.Request.Cookies.ContainsKey("FirstTimeUser"))
    {
        context.Response.Cookies.Delete("FirstTimeUser");
        context.Response.Redirect("/special-first-timer-page");
    }

    await next();
});

app.UseCookieAuthentication(options =>
{
    ...

    options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
    {
        OnSignedIn = context =>
        {
            var userRecord = userService.GetUser(context.Principal.Identity.Name);

            if (userRecord == null)
            {
                userService.CreateUser(context.Principal.Identity.Name);
                context.Response.Cookies.Append("FirstTimeUser", "true");
            }
            else
            {
                userService.RecordLogin(userRecord);
            }

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    };
});
```

This works, but doesn't seem ideal.  Is it possible to successfully redirect during an Authentication middleware event?  Am I missing a point even trying to do so?

Comment: Why do you feel it doesn't seem ideal?  Also, should your `app.Use()` be `else await next();`.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the `else await`!  I suppose I could say less ideal simply because if the redirect set during the `OnSignedIn` event worked there wouldn't need to be an additional piece of middleware.  My main motivation for the question is that I don't understand where in the pipeline the redirect I set in `OnSignedIn` is being rolled back.

Comment: I would suspect that an event callback does not alter the outcome of the pipeline...